# File size less than error

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to set up my batch file to error out if my file size is less than a specific size (in this case if it equals zero)

I used the same format as I had for a greater than portion of the script, but it is failing

```
:: Check size of input files 
call "%DIR_BAT%\CreateLAFMessage.bat" "%~n0.bat-> %STEP_NBR% - check for size of LOM_AA_2.dat and LOM_AI.dat" %_LAF_MSG_DETAILS%
set ERROR_MSG="%DIR_IP_INTERFACES%\LOM_AA_2.dat" ZERO Byte File
set file="%DIR_IP_INTERFACES%\LOM_AA_2.dat"
set minbytesize=0
FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN (%file%) DO set size=%%~zA
if %size% LSS %minbytesize% (
    echo.File is ^> %minbytesize% bytes
) ELSE (
    goto ON_ERROR
)
set ERROR_MSG="%DIR_IP_INTERFACES%\LOM_AI.dat" ZERO Byte File
set file="%DIR_IP_INTERFACES%\LOM_AI.dat"
FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN (%file%) DO set size=%%~zA
if %size% LSS %minbytesize% (
    echo.File is ^> %minbytesize% bytes
) ELSE (
    goto ON_ERROR
)
```

Comment: For `0` bytes you cannot go less than, so do `if %size% EQU %minbytesize%` or if you are looking for less or equal do try `if %size% LEQ %minbytesize%`

Comment: Thanks! I completely glossed over that line

Comment: So it solved your problem?

Comment: Why are you createing 2 `for` loops to do the same thing for multiple files? you know we can use just one loop? Also, for /f is not needed here, plain for will do.

Comment: That did solve my problem. Thanks. As for the 2 for loops, I am not certain. I did not write the code. I took it from what somebody else was creating, and attempted to adjust it to fit my needs. This is my very first foray into writing batch scripts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my Comment, a file cannot be less than `0 bytes` therefore using `if.. LSS..` will not ever match below `0`. Instead use `EQU` of for higher than `0` numbers, `LEQ`

That said, why are you using 2 for loops for the same function, but different files? We can run a single loop and eliminate the `Else` we also do not need the `for /f` but a simple `for` loop.

```
@echo off
set "DIR_IP_INTERFACES=D:\SomeDIR"
set "files=%DIR_IP_INTERFACES%\LOM_AA_2.dat %DIR_IP_INTERFACES%\LOM_AI.dat"
set "minbytesize=0"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR %%A IN (%files%) DO (
   set "file=%%A"
   set "size=%%~zA"
   if !size! GTR !minbytesize! call :ON_ERROR
   if !size! EQU !minbytesize! echo %%A ^= !size! bytes
)
goto :EOF
:ON_ERROR
rem do your other stuff here when on_error label is called...
echo %file% is not 0 it is !size!
```

Answer (score 1):

In what way is it "failing?"

Perhaps because you are executing

```
if %size% LSS %minbytesize%
```

which is true if the size of the file is LESS than the `minbytesize` (you are then reporting "greater than")

Why are you using `for /f` which reads each line of the file and executes the `set` **for each line** of the file??

If all you are doing is finding the size of the file, a plain `for` will be far faster.

Comment: It was the LSS. And for the for portion, I was copying from a piece of code earlier in the script that was written by somebody else. I am new to batch writing. Thanks for the suggestion for edits!