# Check file size in Windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-io

I want to check file size in a Windows batch script. It seems like my script is exiting instead of moving on to the next step in the script. The file condition should not generate an error and should move on to the next step. But I must be missing something or have something incorrect in the following:

```
:: Check size of input files 
call "%DIR_BAT%\CreateLAFMessage.bat" "%~n0.bat-> %STEP_NBR% - check for size of LOM_AA_2.dat and LOM_AI.dat" %_LAF_MSG_DETAILS%
set ERROR_MSG="%DIR_IP_INTERFACES%\LOM_AA_2.dat" ZERO Byte File
set file="%DIR_IP_INTERFACES%\LOM_AA_2.dat"
set maxbytesize=0
FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN (%file%) DO set size=%%~zA
if %size% NEQ %maxbytesize% (
    echo.File is ^<> %maxbytesize% bytes
) ELSE (
    goto ON_ERROR
)
set ERROR_MSG="%DIR_IP_INTERFACES%\LOM_AI.dat" ZERO Byte File
set file="%DIR_IP_INTERFACES%\LOM_AI.dat"
FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN (%file%) DO set size=%%~zA
if %size% NEQ %maxbytesize% (
    echo.File is ^<> %maxbytesize% bytes
) ELSE (
    goto ON_ERROR
)
```

Comment: So are you working on a project with someone else?  Your code looks almost identical to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50155762/file-size-less-than-error)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File size less than error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50155762/file-size-less-than-error)

Comment: yes we are working together on same project. he is out rest of today and tomorrow and while we are further along...now the batch is just stopping (no error, which it should not generate an error)...which is undesirable results, we would expect it to keep going

Comment: `^<>` is an incorrect escape method. Unless you want to create a file, use `^<^>` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You have enabled the `Usebackq` option in the for loop. This option uses a different style of quoting:

- Double quotes for long file names in "filenameset".
- Single quotes for 'Text string to process'
- Backquotes for `command to process`

Therefore, adding the double quotes tells the for loop to process the file.

```
@echo off
set "file=%DIR_IP_INTERFACES%\LOM_AA_2.dat"
set MAXBYTESIZE=0

for /f "usebackq" %%A in ("%file%") do set /a size=%%~zA

if %size% GTR %MAXBYTESIZE% (
    echo(%file% is too large
) else (
    echo(%file% is ^<^> %size% bytes long
)

pause
```